# Ruby on Rails: If Else based on params[:example]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model-view-controller

I have a controller Orders. This controller does different things based on the POST request. 
When a User buys a product, it goes to his stock. So only products in stock can be sold. Stock table has a product_id column. Simply, when a user is on products/product_id page orders must be a buy, when is on stocks/stock_id page order must be sell.

Routes.rb:

```
resources :products, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :orders, only: [:create]
end

resources :stocks, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :orders, only: [:create]
end
```

Rake Routes:

```
products_orders POST       /products/:product_id/orders(.:format) orders#create
products_index GET        /products(.:format) products#index
product GET        /products/:id(.:format) products#show
stocks_orders POST       /stocks/:stock_id/orders(.:format) orders#create
stocks_index GET        /stocks(.:format) stocks#index
stock GET        /stock/:id(.:format) stocks#show
```

My Models:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :orders
    has_many :stocks
end

class Stock < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product
end
```

So I did this:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
def create
    if params[:product_id].present?
        order.type = 'buy'

    elsif params[:stock_id].present?
        order.type = 'sell'
    end
end
end
```

Is this code secure? There is a way to do it better? 
Is right to use this code based on params[:product_id] and params[:stock_id] ?

```
if params[:product_id].present?
    order.type = 'buy'

elsif params[:stock_id].present?
    order.type = 'sell'
end
```

Is possible in some way to inject a params in the request? 
For example inject params[:product_id] to stoks/stock_id/orders doing some damage? For Example with curl.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993664/rails-create-action-with-if-else-based-on-paramsexample?rq=1 asked y'day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is possible in some way to inject a params in the request? For example inject params[:product_id] to stoks/stock_id/orders doing some damage? For Example with curl

Yes. Nothing stops you to send a request to `/stocks/123/orders?product_id=123`. As a result `params[:product_id]` is going to be present and the order will receive the wrong type.

What about creating a separate controller for every type of an order?

```
resources :products, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :product_orders, only: [:create]
end

resources :stocks, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :stock_orders, only: [:create]
end
```

Then `ProductOrdersController` will be as simple as:

```
class ProductOrdersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    order.type = 'buy'
  end
end
```

Then `StockOrdersController` is going to be something like this:

```
class StockOrdersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    order.type = 'sell'
  end
end
```

This will help you to stop rely on passed `params` and get rid of the `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much Igor. So in this case I use the same Order model for two controllers, is this right?

Comment: Depends on the logic of your app, but I assume yes

Comment: Ok. In your opinion is better to use just one model Order or create two model StockOrder and ProductOrder ?